# Why did Hashem change Adam’s creation specifically because Chiram declared himself a god?

Tags: midrash, ezekiel--the-book, bava-batra

Bava Basra 75a-b (translation mine, bracketed insertions follow Rashbam ad. loc.):

> מאי (יחזקאל כח, יג) מלאכת תופיך ונקביך בך אמר רב יהודה אמר רב אמר לו הקדוש ברוך הוא לחירם מלך צור בך נסתכלתי ובראתי נקבים נקבים באדם ואיכא דאמרי הכי קאמר בך נסתכלתי וקנסתי מיתה על אדם הראשון
>
> What is “The worksmanship of your drums and of your holes”? Rav Yehudah said that Rav said, G-d said to Hiram king of Tyre: In you did I peer [I saw that you would declare yourself a god] and I made many holes [referring to the digestive tract] in man. Others explain that this is what He was saying: In you did I peer and I decreed death on Adam.

There were others in history who declared themselves gods. Shemos Rabbah 8:2 notes that four in Tanach declared themselves gods: Chiram (as above), Nevuchadnetzar (Yeshaya 14:14), Paroh (Yechezkel 29:3), and Yoash (Divrei HaYamim 2:24:17). So why is it specifically on Chiram’s account that Hashem added a digestive tract or decreed death?

Comment: G-d didn't specifically make the digestive tract on Chiram's account. Rather, what we should bring away with this is that G-d designed the digestive tract so that man could not claim divinity. Rabbi Yehudah is quoting Rav who is saying that G-d said to Chiram, etc. I don't understand the question

Comment: @ezra Hashem said to Chiram that since you claimed divinity, I made man with these flaws to uproot your claim. If you want to interpret it as the generality I have no problem with that, but then why does the Passuk discuss this by Chiram specifically?